# After changed theme, magento 2 still output static files from old theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I've change the website and store view to a new theme at content->Design Configuration. But when i visit frontend, all the static files are keeping at `http://domain.com/pub/static/version1530690579/frontend/Oldvendorname/oldthemename/en_US/css/styles-l.css`,

it should be 
`http://domain.com/pub/static/version1530690579/frontend/Newvendorname/newthemename/en_US/css/styles-l.css`

Comment: Did you clear Magento cache and Browser cache?

Comment: already clean all the cache

Comment: @hkguile same problem with me. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

How did you change the theme? I think you have mistakenly changed the theme globally or for website level.

There is an option to change the theme at store view level also. I think your old theme is set on the store view level, so it is taking priority.

To verify, go to **Content** > **Design (Configuration)** and check that you have applied the new theme at the store view level.

[image: Store View Theme Settings]

If above is not the case, then remove content from pub/static/frontend and var/cache, var/page_cache folder and reload the website.

Comment: all tried, seems not related

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate the static files by running this command in ssh:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```